# How to print data member's address(in class offset) with "cout"

Tags: c++, pointers, datamember

I have a class below:

```
class A
{
public:
    double a;
    float b;
    double c;
};
```

I want to print data member offset in class, than I use:

```
double A::* pm = &A::a;
cout << *(int *)&pm << endl;
```

It works well and print '0', but I don't want to use intermediate variable `pm`

```
cout << *(int *)&A::a << endl;
```

I got compile error with : **Invalid type conversion**

Comment: You should clarify your question since what you are printing is not an offset, offset should be the difference between the member address and the class instance address, as mentioned by @WhozCraig `std::offsetof` does that.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis: This could be a flaky, non-portable way to print a member's offset, if that's how member pointers are represented (which is usually the case), and if a member pointer happens to have the same size as `int`. But yes, `std::offsetof` is the portable way to get an offset.

Comment: @WhozCraig I don’t believe that `std::offsetof` exists. It’s a macro, it doesn’t reside in `std`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph roger that. you're correct. in `cstddef`. thx for the correction.

Comment: Note a pointer to data member doen't have to be the same as the offset of that member. Some compilers use a different representation.

Comment: Worth noting that `offsetof` has UB unless the type is standard-layout.

Answer (score 0):

With *offset* is assumed that you refer *offset in bytes*.

You could try this solution:

```
(size_t) &(((A*)0)->a) // prints 0
```

Actually this is the implementation of the macro `offsetof` as [WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972/whozcraig) suggested.

```
 ...
cout << "A::a => " << (size_t) &(((A*)0)->a)
     << "\nA::b => " << (size_t) &(((A*)0)->b)
     << "\nA::c => " << (size_t) &(((A*)0)->c);
 ...
```

Combined with your data, previous snippet will print:

```
A::a => 0
A::b => 8
A::c => 16
```